# Mejorar codigo de lectura CSV python

Tags: python, csv

como se podria mejorar esta función para quitar el i = 0... He probado con enumerate() pero no me ha funcionado bien. Estoy probando sin librerías.

```
>  def readFileCsv(self, path):
>         with open(path) as file:
>             reader = csv.reader(file)
>             i = 0
>             CSVData = []
>             for row in reader:
>                 CSVData.append([])
>                 for column in row:
>                     CSVData[i].append(column)
>                 i += 1
>         print(CSVData)
>         return CSVData
```

Gracias :)

Comment: Y si pones el enumerate y modificas el for? for i, row in enumerate(reader)

Comment: El ciclo para las columnas entiendo que es innecesario, en `row` ya tienes una `tupla` que es similar a un objeto lista como el que vuelves a construir

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @Dante S. en principio así si funciona, gracias :)
Haría falta añadir un try / catch?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho lo quería guardar por si tengo que coger un valor concreto del CSV poder coger por fila y columna: ejemplo[fila1][col2]
Porque tengo un CSV en el que quiero filtrar datos por X parametros.
Gracias (:

Comment: De nada c: Que te hace pensar que el try-except podria ser necesario?

Comment: @DanteS. por capturar posibles errores como que quiera abrir el CSV y no exista.
Por aprender a mejorar el codigo jeje TY! C:

Comment: En ese caso, supongo que si hace falta.